# Only one xterm window on Kali

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, xterm

I have a Kali virtual machine installed on virtualbox, that I use for some university assignments. One of those assignments required to start a small LAN using xterm, the professor gave us an archive with all the necessary files to start eh five VMs that should be virtually networked:

```
alice.cow
bob.cow
dns.cow
eve.cow
linux
rootfs.ext4
start_net.sh
vde_switch
```

The .sh file should only start the five machines with xterm

```
xterm -T switch -e ./vde_switch -s s1 &
xterm -T alice -e ./linux ubd0=alice.cow,rootfs.ext4 eth0=vde,s1,88:A1:1C:EA:11:CE,1 mem=64M &
xterm -T bob -e ./linux ubd0=bob.cow,rootfs.ext4 eth0=vde,s1,B0:BB:0B:B0:BB:0B,2 mem=64M &
xterm -T eve -e ./linux ubd0=eve.cow,rootfs.ext4 eth0=vde,s1,BA:DE:7E:BA:DE:7E,3 mem=64M &
xterm -T dns -e ./linux ubd0=dns.cow,rootfs.ext4 eth0=vde,s1,00:00:00:DD:DD:DD,4 mem=64M &
```

but when I try to run it with `./start_net.sh` it only starts the switch correctly, the other machines are not started. If I try to close the switch window, then all the other machines are started and immediately shut down.
I tried to unzip the archive on my machine, which is a LinuxMint, and everything works fine. Is it a problem with Kali or something else? I don't think it is a problem of virtualbox as also the professor runs this exercise on virtualbox, but he uses an Ubuntu vm.

Comment: um, "a LAN" has nothing to do with "Termux" (which is a terminal emulator for Android, so now I'm very confused). "Files to run a network": you don't "run" a network; a network "is". I guess you mean your job is to run multiple virtual machines (?) that are virtually networked (?). Would that be possible?

Comment: Kali is *really* not the distro you should be using! See Kali's own [should I be using Kali?](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) article. This is not a task for the special-purpose tool that Kali Linux is, and you in your current situation are also not Kali's audience. Yes, it's *because Kali is not set up to do the things you want to do*, and setting it up would probably be more complex than the actual task.

Comment: This question is explicitly geared towards solving some university assignments. They should be in touch with their staff instead of stackexchange.

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry for the mistake, of course I meant xterm (as I wrote in the title and also at some point inside the question) and not termux. And sorry for my english...yes, I mean that I have to run multiple vm that are virtually connected. I tried to use Kali as the course is held by three professors: two of them use Kali and one Ubuntu, but they always said that we can choose whatever distro we prefer because our tasks should not depend on the distro. I guess I'll just switch to Ubuntu...

Comment: @Hermann yeah I know that, but professor did not reply to my emails so I tried to ask here...